# Fastest server client communication?

Tags: android, tcp, udp

I wanted to make a very fast android app to communicate with my home server running on ubuntu.

So I have made something with json flask, TCP sockets and UDP sockets.

I want information about my network, temperature reading, log events, devices that I made, my LED strip and more in the future.

The thing is I want the response of the LED strip as fast as possible. 
But also get other information.

So that it feels very reactive. Also in the future I wanted to implement something with my phone's x,y and z sensors. This has also to be very responsive.

Can anyone help me out which tech or something else is good for this kind off application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]    We have used UDP connection in the driverless metro project. It is very fast but not reliable. So you need to write crosscheck statements with it.

```
My advice and answer is;
You can use UDP and also create a header for checking process. For example 2 Byte header for network checking. We did this in the Big Driverless metro project.
You should send the data each time when the receiver catch the data.

Sample;

[ 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 ] <-- 1 Byte, 8 Bit 

0 --> Did receiver catch the data ? 
1 --> If receiver catch data, make this bit 1 and resend to the sender.
2 --> Receiver to Sender
3 --> 
8 --> Backup

You need to create a header byte data, and put your checking statements in it.
```

## How to send temp

If you use UDP or TCP we can send ONU BYTE as a minimum data. Namely we can't send Bit. 1 Byte = 8 Bit

Sender to Receiver
1. Byte [ 
         0 Bit --> Get temperature information
         1 Bit -->
2. Byte [ Free]

Send every second and listen the receiver maybe It sends the information we don't need to request anymore. Check Receiver' first byte' first bit.
if its 0 keep sending
if its 1 ohh receiver sent temperature information look second byte its temperature

Receiver to Sender
Listen Sender, If sender sends data check first byte' first bit if its 0 doesn't care. If it 1 The sender requests temperature information from us. Send the temperature information to the sender. make first byte' first bit 1. make second byte temperature information.

1.Byte [ 0.bit zero or one]
2.Byte [ temperature inf]

Comment: Aright aright. This sounds very cool.
What do you mean by checking statements? Like a acknowledge?
So every time a packet has been send a bit is put to 1 so acknowledge right?

Comment: For example, You will always send data until you get any response from receiver. Receiver listens the X port and if data comes receiver checks with some conditions. and after that Receiver sends response to sender. OK dont send me data because I got your message.

Comment: Very awesome answer, very complete. Thanks a lot :D.
I now understand what you mean.
You are constant sending information until a receiver has acknowledged it by changing a bit in the packet. As you said :P

Excuse me mister for asking another question.
So say I wanted to send from server to client temperature information in a byte form or integer don't know yet, how would this look like?

Comment: Something like this =>
Server sends constant data with header
Receiver: Got data, change data bit in header, send to server
Server detects change in bit in the header and knows its acknowledged
Server sends temperature data+networkdata+etc+etc
Receiver reads data
And then I am stuck...haha

Comment: it is a little bit complicated, but i wish it helps a little bit to you. Good luck. Good question Upvote from me.

Comment: Thanks mister. You are awesome :D:D.  This will help me a lot.